# Is there a way to programmatically connect to a Passpoint/Hotspot2.0 network via EAP-TTLS?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying to create either a WifiConfiguration object or PasspointConfiguration object in my Android application that will allow me to connect a device to a Passpoint network upon being enabled.

I've tried to connect by building a WifiConfiguration object and adding it to the WifiManager, then enabling it.

I have also tried to build a PasspointConfiguration object, but when I try to run WifiManager.addOrUpdatePasspointConfiguration() with the PasspointConfiguration object, the app crashes with an IllegalArgumentException. I'm assuming that this is an invalid configuration issue.

```java
// WifiConfiguration/WifiEnterpriseConfiguration approach
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
wc.isHomeProviderNetwork = true;
wc.FQDN = this.domain;
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setIdentity(user);
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setPassword(key);
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setAnonymousIdentity(this.outerID);
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setRealm(this.realm);
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setDomainSuffixMatch(this.domain);
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(this.eapMethod);
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(this.phase2Auth);
wifiEnterpriseConfig.setCaCertificate(this.cert);

wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);

wc.enterpriseConfig = wifiEnterpriseConfig;

wifiManager.disconnect();
this.networkID = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
wifiManager.enableNetwork(this.networkID, true);
```

```java
// PasspointConfiguration approach
Credential.UserCredential userCredential = new Credential.UserCredential();
userCredential.setEapType(21);
userCredential.setPassword(key);
userCredential.setUsername(user);
userCredential.setNonEapInnerMethod("MS-CHAP-V2");

Credential credential = new Credential();
credential.setRealm(this.realm);
credential.setUserCredential(userCredential);
credential.setCertCredential(null);
credential.setCaCertificate(null);
credential.setClientPrivateKey(null);
credential.setClientCertificateChain(null);

HomeSp homeSp = new HomeSp();
homeSp.setFqdn(this.domain);
homeSp.setFriendlyName(this.friendlyName);

PasspointConfiguration passpointConfiguration = new PasspointConfiguration();
passpointConfiguration.setCredential(credential);
passpointConfiguration.setHomeSp(homeSp);

wifiManager.addOrUpdatePasspointConfiguration(passpointConfiguration);
```

I expect the application to connect the device to the Passpoint/Hotspot2.0 network upon one of the configurations being added to the WifiManager.

The first approach does not produce an error, but does not connect the application to the network.

The following is the stack trace from the PasspointConfiguration IllegalArgumentException:

```
Process: com.***.***.***, PID: 4101
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.addOrUpdatePasspointConfiguration(WifiManager.java:1483)
        at com.***.***.***.models.<PrivateClass>.<PrivateMethod1>(<PrivateClass>.java:197)
        at com.***.***.***.models.<PrivateClass>.<PrivateMethod2>(<PrivateClass>.java:219)
        at com.***.***.***.models.<PrivateClass>.<PrivateMethod3>(<PrivateClass>.java:116)
        at com.***.***.***.UserView.<PrivateMethod4>(UserView.java:178)
        at com.***.***.***.UserView.access$100(UserView.java:34)
        at com.***.***.***.UserView$2.onClick(UserView.java:200)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7327)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key used in userCredential.setPassword(key) must be base 64 encoded before setting it to the userCredential.

Answer (score 0):

credential.setCaCertificate(null);
must not be null for passpoint as today.

Comment: Hi Steven -- I've added a certificate and I'm no longer getting an IllegalArgumentException. The Passpoint configuration now appears in the list of enabled Passpoint configurations returned by WifiManager.getPasspointConfigurations(), but the device is not connecting to the Passpoint automatically. Is there another step that I'm missing to finally connect to the Passpoint?

Comment: @jacobpaisley How did you generate CA certificate which you added in the Passpoint profile? I have read at https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-passpoint#file_composition that is a "must have" for TTLS but I am not sure how it is created. The clients will be authenticated via the RADIUS server. Do I have to generate it on the RADIUS server for every user I create? Please help since PKI got me all confused.

Comment: @jacobpaisley Did you find out why the device did not connect?

Answer (score -1):

addOrUpdatePasspointConfiguration has been removed in Android 11 .
Are you able to do this on Android 11 using WifiNetworkSuggestion ?

Comment: This is not really an answer.  I'd suggest making it a comment.