# Android Passpoint Configuration - is a X509Certificate required?

Tags: java, android, react-native, networking

I have a react native app and trying to configure a passpoint network natively i.e. not using the .config file.

Now the code block below works - It creates a Hotspot 2.0 configuration on the device e.g. Settings > Wifi> Advances > Hotspot 2.0.

I have done the same thing for iOS and **did not** have to set a CA Certificate to get it to work.

On Android, if I do not set the CA certificate I get an `IllegalArgumentException`.  Is it required on Android to set this CA Certificate? If not, why throw the `IllegalArgumentException`?

```
Credential.UserCredential userCredential = new Credential.UserCredential();
        userCredential.setEapType(21);
        userCredential.setPassword("myPassword");
        userCredential.setUsername("myUsername");
        userCredential.setNonEapInnerMethod("MS-CHAP-V2");

        Credential credential = new Credential();
        credential.setRealm("passpoint.myDomain.com");
        credential.setUserCredential(userCredential);
        credential.setCaCertificate((X509Certificate) cert); // Why do I need to set this? 

        HomeSp homeSp = new HomeSp();
        homeSp.setFqdn("myDomain.io");
        homeSp.setFriendlyName("My Passpoint");

        PasspointConfiguration passpointConfiguration = new PasspointConfiguration();
        passpointConfiguration.setCredential(credential);
        passpointConfiguration.setHomeSp(homeSp);
```

I cannot find anything in the docs to say it is required.  If anybody had any experience using any of the classes above, I'd appreciate some insight into this.

I came across this post and one of the answers did say it is required but would like if anybody could confirm this; [Is there a way to programmatically connect to a Passpoint/Hotspot2.0 network via EAP-TTLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798610/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-passpoint-hotspot2-0-network-via)

**EDIT**
I came across this on the Android 11 release notes and is exactly what I am trying to achieve for Android 10 and lower.

[image]